# How do I automatically subtract time data of previous row from current row in Excel?

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, subtraction, excel-2019

Here's what I want to achieve:
[image: Here's what I want to achieve]

In the example, I manually subtracted the value of the previous cell from the cell.
For example:
**For cell C2, I used =A2-A1

For cell C3, I used =A3-A2

For cell C4, I used =A4-A3**
And so on.

How do I make this process automatic so that every time I enter a value in the column A, the last cell of a column would automatically get subtracted from new entered value. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an actual Excel table out of this data. Select the whole "table" and use
*Insert* -> *Table*

Then after you enter a new value at the bottom of the table it will become part of the table and the formula in column C will automatically be created.

For this to work you need that column C would have the same formula (can be pasted down). E.g. for me this formula worked:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A2-A1,"")`

[image]

To make formatting like you want you can change the number format of column C to:
`[mm] "Minutes"`
Deciding from the image in the question it seems you know how to do it.

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Didn't even have to convert it to table. I couldn't merge some cells after I converted it to a table and your formula is working well without converting it. But there is a slight problem. Take a look at this screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/DRX5TXZ/image.png
How do I fix this?

Comment: Does 12 AM really represent a new day?

Comment: Pls check again. Format it as yyyy-mm-dd so that you will see actual date. My tests show that if it's really another day, then the formula works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0OuP.png

Comment: Oh, do I have to create a separate column for dates?
If I have to, can I merge the cells for the same date, not repeating the same value?

Comment: Only for testing purposes, to find out the date which is seen by Excel engine. You *see* time, but actually there is a full date in that cell, which we want to find out.

Comment: Added date column, didn't work. Reapplied the formula, same. Changed A to B in the formula and reapplied, same result.
https://i.ibb.co/Tk7LXT2/image.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226200/discussion-between-zygd-and-um9vdao).